# Introduce delays to every incoming requests for mysql server

Tags: mysql, server

I have to test how application responds if the mysql server takes some time(like 1 minute). So, i would like the mysql to wait for a minute before processing the request. I have check  mysql configuration but none seems to be doing what i needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SELECT SLEEP(60);`  Or add `SLEEP(60)` to an existing `SELECT`.

Or add a `TRIGGER` to a table that will be accessed, and have it do a sleep.  This may be the "least invasive" in that it does not require changing the application.

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting into my.cnf or my.ini [mysqld] section

```
init_connect=SELECT SLEEP(60) 
OR
init_connect=SELECT SLEEP(60);
```

Not tested, just a non-intrusive idea.
Not sure your clients will appreciate this delay before they can
accomplish anything they need to do today.
Since you are 'TESTING' this should not get into your PRODUCTION world.

Please view profile.